# onClick not working on Firefox - is working on Chrome

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I am using a Material UI `Textfield` component. When a user clicks on the `Textfield` it changes the state.

This is working correctly on Chrome but is not changing the state for Firefox.

I have tried wrapping the component in a `<div>` and putting the onClick there but that did not work

```
const EditableText = ({ value, name, multiline, variant, id, update }) => {
const classes = useStyles()

const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false)
const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState(false)
const [tempEditingValue, setTempEditingValue] = useState(value)

const handleEditClick = () => setIsEditing(!isEditing)
const handleMouseOver = () => setMouseOver(!mouseOver)
const handleEditChange = (evt) => setTempEditingValue(evt.target.value)
const resetTempEditingValue = () => {
    setTempEditingValue(value)
    setIsEditing(false)
}
const submitEdit = async (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    update(id, {[name]: tempEditingValue})
    setIsEditing(false)
}

   return (
            <TextField
                className={classes.text}
                onClick={handleEditClick}
                disabled={isEditing}
                multiline={multiline}
                value={value}
                name={name}
                onMouseEnter={handleMouseOver}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseOver}
                InputProps={{
                    classes: {
                        disabled: classes.disabled,
                        root: classes[variant]
                    }
                }}
            />
    )
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: It seams is a bug in `FormcControl` component. report it as an issue on GitHub page

Comment: For other people with this problem, here is the issue and a possible solution: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13988